# Where do I find the reference for TO_DATE format string

Tags: teradata

I need to convert a string formatted as MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI plus AM/PM, but can't find a complete reference to the format string to find how to specify the AM/PM part.

I would certainly appreciate information on how to do this, but would appreciate a link to a good source of documentation for this even more.

:EDIT

```
SELECT top 1
v.CalendarDateTime
,TO_TIMESTAMP(v.CalendarDateTime,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MIAM') as CalendarDateTimeTS
--,CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP(v.CalendarDateTime,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MIAM') AS TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYYBHH:MIBT') AS CalendarDateTimeTS2
```

> 12/03/2015 03:00AM    12/3/2015 03:00:00.000000

The commented out line produces a "DateTime field overflow" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `TO_TIMESTAMP` instead of `TO_DATE`.

The only bad thing about the Oracle function is the resulting datatype of `TIMESTAMP(6)` which can't be changed:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('12/03/2015 03:00AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MIAM')
```

Using Teradata's `FORMAT` you can specify the timestamp precision, but it's less flexible than Oracle's, the string must match the format exactly:

```
CAST('12/03/2015 03:00AM' AS TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYYbHH:MIT')
```

On the Teradata site you'll find the (slow) online docu, e.g. [TO_DATE formats](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_151K/format_arg_format_elements_TO_DATE.html) or [Teradata FORMATs](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1143_151K/Format_Phrases.040.47.html#ww620520). Of course you should download the [full documentation CD](http://www.info.teradata.com/templates/eSrchResults.cfm?prodline=&txtpid=&txtrelno=&txtttlkywrd=CDROM&rdsort=Date&srtord=Desc&nm=Documentation%20CD%20Images%20-%20Teradata%20Database%20and%20Teradata%20Tools%20and%20Utilities) for your release.

Comment: The TO_TIMESTAMP works, but the CAST returns a "DateTime field overflow". I put the code into my question for reference.

Comment: @Metaphor:  You can't reduce the precision of a Timestamp (stupid, I know, blame Standard SQL), so better use the 2nd version instead, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please tell us at least which programming language are you using.
Normally it would be something like "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI a" but we need to know first you language.

Comment: This is Teradata SQL. I set the tag for Teradata but neglected to mention it in the text.